# VBA loop to save files in specific location with specific name

Tags: excel, vba

This is the loop I'm using

```
  Do While myFile <> ""

  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=myPath & myFile)

'Texto para colunas
            Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
    Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1 _
    ), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array(19, 1), Array _
    (20, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(22, 1), Array(23, 1), Array(24, 1), Array(25, 1), Array(26, 1), _
    Array(27, 1), Array(28, 1), Array(29, 1), Array(30, 1), Array(31, 1), Array(32, 1), Array( _
    33, 1), Array(34, 1), Array(35, 1), Array(36, 1), Array(37, 1)), DecimalSeparator:="." _
    , ThousandsSeparator:=",", TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit


'Save and close the file

 wb.Close SaveChanges:=True


'next file
  myFile = Dir
```

Loop

I'm trying to make it save them in a different folder, and with a different name. even if i use something like this :

```
wb.SaveAs "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test\data\wb.data"
```

To just run the sub and save in another folder, the code will try to save them all with the same name. How can i make the loop change the file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will work. It just names the the file as wb1, wb2, wb3, etc. You can easily adjust using the same structure.

```
i = 1

Do While myFile <> ""

    '... text to columns code


    wb.SaveAs "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test\data\wb" & i & ".data"

    i = i +1

    'next file
  myFile = Dir

Loop
```

Comment: Hi, it gives me a syntax error, i don't really understand how to use variables like this in VBA, what does ( wb & i & ".dat") means?

Comment: Hi again, i changed to ( wb" & i & ".dat") and it works thanks

Comment: @mike - good on you for figuring out the missing `"` :). Glad it worked. Do you understand the variable now? The use of `i` simply attaches a number to the end of the string `wb` so you have different files each time (as i increments by 1 while the loop is in effect).